# When do session records get deleted when using sfPDOSessionStorage?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I just started messing around with having my application store sessions in the database using doctrine/symfony.  I can see sessions get created when I access my web app, but I don't see the rows going away, even after the session should've expired.

I searched for calls of sfPDOSessionStorage's sessionDestroy and could not find any obvious place where it is called.

Does anyone know how this works?  Symfony's documentation (especially post v1.2) is pretty bad when it comes to storing session information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions database must have been cleaned periodically with the [`sessionGC`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_3/sfPDOSessionStorage#method_sessiongc) function. If it does not, check your [`session.gc_probability`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) and [`session.gc_divisor`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor) php.ini settings.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, by default session records remain in the database after expiry. This can be useful for logging and reports but obviousl requires further development to remove them.